# SQL Server Query to Get all the particular column available in all the Tables of a Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get to know about a particular column, where and all in all the tables it is available across a Database. (Provided Column name is same in all tables)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: For now i am using SQL Server But Similar Changes i have to Do in MY SQL as well.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server ***INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS*** view allows you to get information about all columns for all tables and views within a database.

Using following query you can find all the views and tables having a specific column name.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,TABLE_NAME 
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME ='YOUR_COLUMN_NAME'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c
JOIN        sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE '%MyName%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE Table_Schema = DATABASE()  
AND Column_Name LIKE '%Column_name%' ;
```

Table_Schema = DATABASE() this condition select by default database name which you are working and works for better performance

Comment: Thanks but DATABASE() is not seems supported in SQL server or not sure is there any work around to use that.

Comment: this will work on Mysql for sql server i need to check

Comment: you can't use Table_Schema = DATABASE() this condition in sql server you have to select one DB and than use query without this condition